# combine different sorting result in one query

Tags: postgresql

```
tasktime
  id | name | start_date | end_date ...
  1  | a    | 2016-12-22 | 2017-01-01
  2  | b    | 2016-05-01 | 2016-05-31
  3  | c    | 2016-06-01 | 2016-12-25
```

should I use group or ..
I tried below query get result: 1 2 3
even if I change `start_date asc` or `end_date desc` nothing happen,

```
SELECT
 tt.* 
 FROM tasktime tt 
 ORDER BY tt.name asc NULLS LAST
     , tt.start_date desc NULLS LAST
     , tt.end_date asc NULLS LAST
```

**UPDATE**

I want combine different sorting result

```
SELECT
     tt.* 
     FROM tasktime tt
     ORDER BY tt.end_date asc NULLS LAST

then use above result 

     ORDER BY tt.start_date desc NULLS LAST

then use above result

     ORDER BY tt.name asc NULLS LAST
```

please close this question ... I realised what I want , and this question is totally wrong

Comment: `order by end_date asc, start_date desc , name asc`

Comment: can't use nulls last ?

Comment: you can - I thought you ask about the column order

Comment: How is it possible to have order 3 1 2 if you want it sorted by end_date asc? The lowest end_date is in record 2, not record 3. Do you mean you want them in order 2 3 1  ?

Comment: Thanks for reply, no I want 3 1 2 , first check end_date asc (means almose end first) then start_date desc then name asc , but I don't know how to, my query is wrong

Comment: Cross posted: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/158933/sort-multiple-column-with-different-important-level

Comment: Sorry, still not very clear... you want record 3 before the other ones but it is not clear the criteria you want to use to have it first. Try to explain by word the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @GiacomoDegliEsposti I update in question , I want to combine sorting in one query,  e.g sorting a column get result_a then use result_a sorting b column ....

Comment: Sorry... what you are asking is solved with the clause "order by end_date asc, start_date desc , name asc", like you were told from the beginning. You probably are trying to solve a different problem, can you explain it by words (instead of by sql) ?

Answer (score 0):

Like here?

```
t=# create table tasktime (id int, name text, start_date date, end_date date);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into tasktime values (1,'a','2016-12-22', '2017-01-01'), (2, 'b', '2016-05-01', '2016-05-31'), (3, 'c', '2016-06-01','2016-12-25');
INSERT 0 3
t=# SELECT
t-#  tt.*
t-#  FROM tasktime tt
t-# order by tt.end_date asc NULLS LAST
t-# , tt.start_date desc NULLS LAST
t-# , tt.name asc NULLS LAST;
 id | name | start_date |  end_date
----+------+------------+------------
  2 | b    | 2016-05-01 | 2016-05-31
  3 | c    | 2016-06-01 | 2016-12-25
  1 | a    | 2016-12-22 | 2017-01-01
(3 rows)
```

Comment: can't use nulls last? why?

Comment: that seems same like my query, why can't use tt.end_date ?

Comment: then what's different between my query in question

Comment: I want sort `end_date asc` then `start_date desc` then `name asc` get result : 3 1 2 . yours just same as I tried before in my question, nothing change ......